# Converting YouTube video to FLAC audio file

Tags: youtube, audio-conversion, flac

I wanted know if it's okay to convert a song from a Youtube video to FLAC so I can open it in Audacity without losing quality to export as an MP3 (192kbps); Wouldn't the FLAC retain the quality of the song so it can be worked on in Audacity?

Comment: YouTube doesn't store audio in FLAC, it stores high quality audio using the AAC format. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Quality_and_formats

Comment: Yes, but I have to convert the video to get the audio so I can modify it in Audacity; if I convert it to MP3, Audacity compresses it again? What do I convert it to so I can work on it in Audacity? I figured FLAC and I can just keep the FLAC files if I need them again.

Comment: I'm not sure what format would be best for Audacity but converting it to multiple formats might not be a good idea for keeping quality

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the audio quality (which is already lossy, due to the YouTube conversion), you might want to try extracting the audio instead of converting it. [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) could come in handy. It requires some basic knowledge of the Command Prompt.

The audio stream in YouTube videos could be AAC or Vorbis (OGG), either of which is a lossy format (it depends on which video format you choose to download: MP4, FLV, WEBM) First you need to determine which type of audio format does your video contain. For this you need to run this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4
```

"video.mp4" is the file name of your video downloaded from YouTube. Look for the line starting with `Stream #0:1: Audio:` - there you'll find the audio format (for MP4 videos it should be AAC).

Now you need to extract the audio, by running this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vn -acodec copy audio.aac
```

- `-vn` means no video
- `-acodec copy` will copy the audio stream without converting it
- `audio.aac` is your output file - you can name it however you want, but the file's extension must correspond with the audio format determined by running the first command.

This should give you the audio file that you can edit in Audacity without converting it (I tried both AAC and OGG and it worked perfectly). And since there is no conversion involved, the extraction process is pretty fast. I've extracted a 151 MB audio file from a 1,35 GB video in less than 15 seconds.

Just remember few things - converting an audio or video file to another format (even lossless, such as FLAC) could cause some quality loss - so whenever possible, try extracting the audio or video streams instead of converting them.

To preserve the quality after editing your audio in Audacity, you should always save it as the Audacity Project (*.aup) for later editing or extract the audio as a playable format - either lossless (such as WAV) or good quality MP3 (you can set the bit rate to 320 kbps, though YouTube videos usually have lower bit rates) or other format of your choice.

Last but not least: if you want a good quality audio, you should probably look for other sources than YouTube (or other video streaming services), since the audio contained in videos is always lower quality - but that's just my suggestion...

Answer (score 0):

If you know you are allowed to do so (you are not breaking any laws like copyright by doing this), you can use [youtube-dl](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl) to download the source audio files only, without video.

Youtube already pre-converts the video and audio to different formats to suit the needs of devices with smaller screens and lower display resolution, so if you need a version with reduced bandwidth, you can find one already processed by Youtube and download just that.

Once you have installed youtube-dl, use the command line: `youtube-dl -F youtube_video_url_here` you will see something like this output:

```
C:\Users\UserName>youtube-dl -F https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading webpage
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading js player vflFbRRRp
[youtube] dQw4w9WgXcQ: Downloading js player vflFbRRRp
[info] Available formats for dQw4w9WgXcQ:
format code  extension  resolution note
249          webm       audio only tiny   49k , opus @ 50k (48000Hz), 1.18MiB
250          webm       audio only tiny   65k , opus @ 70k (48000Hz), 1.55MiB
140          m4a        audio only tiny  130k , m4a_dash container, mp4a.40.2@128k (44100Hz), 3.27MiB
251          webm       audio only tiny  136k , opus @160k (48000Hz), 3.28MiB
394          mp4        256x144    144p   80k , av01.0.00M.08, 25fps, video only, 1.83MiB
278          webm       256x144    144p   97k , webm container, vp9, 25fps, video only, 2.25MiB
160          mp4        256x144    144p  108k , avc1.4d400c, 25fps, video only, 2.05MiB
395          mp4        426x240    240p  182k , av01.0.00M.08, 25fps, video only, 3.84MiB
242          webm       426x240    240p  217k , vp9, 25fps, video only, 4.04MiB
133          mp4        426x240    240p  289k , avc1.4d4015, 25fps, video only, 4.47MiB
396          mp4        640x360    360p  346k , av01.0.01M.08, 25fps, video only, 7.02MiB
243          webm       640x360    360p  396k , vp9, 25fps, video only, 6.96MiB
134          mp4        640x360    360p  484k , avc1.4d401e, 25fps, video only, 8.26MiB
244          webm       854x480    480p  586k , vp9, 25fps, video only, 10.03MiB
397          mp4        854x480    480p  618k , av01.0.04M.08, 25fps, video only, 12.23MiB
135          mp4        854x480    480p  742k , avc1.4d401e, 25fps, video only, 11.56MiB
247          webm       1280x720   720p 1035k , vp9, 25fps, video only, 17.67MiB
136          mp4        1280x720   720p 1079k , avc1.4d401f, 25fps, video only, 16.72MiB
398          mp4        1280x720   720p 1249k , av01.0.05M.08, 25fps, video only, 25.78MiB
248          webm       1920x1080  1080p 2666k , vp9, 25fps, video only, 58.46MiB
137          mp4        1920x1080  1080p 4642k , avc1.640028, 25fps, video only, 78.97MiB
18           mp4        640x360    360p  601k , avc1.42001E, mp4a.40.2@ 96k (44100Hz), 15.19MiB (best)
```

As you can see there are several items listed with no video resolution but with text "audio only", and these are the ones you're looking for. For best quality, pick the one with the largest bitrate. Here it's the one with 136k, on the line starting with `251`. This means the file ID 251 is the one you want to download. So run the following command:

```
youtube-dl -f 251 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ
```

And you should have the best audio track for this video url. Obviously you have to see which file IDs your video has, so you'll need to run the `-F` command first, as described above.

After that, you might end up with a file which your video or audio editor might not want to recognize. In this example we will end up with a `webm` file which is not an audio format in itself, but a container format, like `mkv`, which can have multiple media files inside. The 251 track contains an audio track in [opus format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opus_(audio_format)).

To convert any audio to FLAC, you can use [ffmpeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\input audio file.webm" "D:\output audio file.flac"
```

Answer (score 0):

The really simplest way; use **youtube-dl** ...

`$ youtube-dl -x --audio-format flac --audio-quality 0 "youtube-url-to-video"`

*e.g. with a Special tweak for Ubuntu 20.04, which doesn't have Python2 ...*

```
$ python3 `which youtube-dl` -x --audio-format flac --audio-quality 0 "https://youtu.be/qTUM8gFyLqo?t=909"
[youtube] qTUM8gFyLqo: Downloading webpage
[youtube] qTUM8gFyLqo: Downloading js player bcf2977e
[youtube] qTUM8gFyLqo: Downloading js player bcf2977e
[download] Destination: Popcorn in 13 versions (chronological evolution)-qTUM8gFyLqo.webm
[download] 100% of 16.41MiB in 00:00
[ffmpeg] Destination: Popcorn in 13 versions (chronological evolution)-qTUM8gFyLqo.flac
Deleting original file Popcorn in 13 versions (chronological evolution)-qTUM8gFyLqo.webm (pass -k to keep)
```

And then of course, audacity takes flac, but also many other formats including mp3...

```
$ audacity "Popcorn in 13 versions (chronological evolution)-qTUM8gFyLqo.flac"
```

*cut all noise before 909 seconds to keep the muppets version;*
*youtube-dl doesn't respect the "?t=909" portion of the url.*

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you need a [FLAC video converter](http://onebestsoft.com/free-flac-converter-windows/), you can get any Youtube video and audio you want.